# Вывести изображение по имени файла

Tags: изображения, php

Добрго времени суток. Помогите разобраться с проблемой..
Есть такой код:

```
<?php
$file = 'up/' . $_GET['id'] . '.' . 'png';
$im = imagecreatefrompng('thefile.png');
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
?>
```

всё отлично, выводит картинку, но если придаю коду вид:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
$file = 'up/' . $_GET['id'] . '.' . 'png';
$im = imagecreatefrompng($file);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
}
else
echo 'не указан id';
?>
```

При заходе на страницу `img.php?id=20131017001012414` браузер говорит, что изображение не может быть показано, так как содержит ошибки. В папке up файл с именем `20131017001012414.png` точно есть.

Comment: попробуйте имя поменьше взять (например 11), или не числовой, а текстовый вариант )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы добавил ещё file_exists() и отдал бы хедер 404 при ошибке:

```
<?php

$myid = ''; if(isset($_GET['id'])) $myid = $_GET['id'];
$file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/up/' . (int)$myid . '.png';

if (!file_exists($file)) { header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"); die('Error 404: Wrong ID or file not found.'); }

$im = imagecreatefrompng($file);
imageAlphaBlending($im, true);
imageSaveAlpha($im, true);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagePng($im);

?>
```

Правда, иногда очень помогает ;)

Comment: И правда так лучше. Спасибо )

Answer (score 2):

Во первых, закоментируйте строки:

```
//header('Content-Type: image/png');
//imagepng($im);
```

И посмотрите что выводит браузер.

Во вторых, лучше всегда указывать абсолютные пути.
Например, если директория up находится на одном уровне со скриптом, то тогда можно сделать так:

```
$file = dirname(__FILE__).'/up/' . $_GET['id'] . '.' . 'png';
```

В третьих так не делать не безопасно. Нужно еще сделать валидацию для `$_GET['id']` (правило №1 - никогда не доверяй данным, которые поступают от пользователя)

```
$file = dirname(__FILE__).'/up/' . str_replace(array('.', '/'), '', $_GET['id']) . '.' . 'png';
```

Comment: В логах пишет:

    2013/11/21 14:11:44 [error] 26214#0: *98 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 10.168.1.39, server: 10.168.1.39, request: "GET /img-up/up/123456.png HTTP/1.1", host: "10.168.1.39", referrer: "http://10.168.1.39/img-up/img.php?id=123456"

В браузере белая страница.
код на данный момент такой:

    <?php 
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $file = dirname(__FILE__).'/up2/' . $_GET['id'] . '.' . 'png';
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($file);}
    else echo 'не указан id';
    ?>

Comment: > (правило №1 - никогда не доверяй данным, которые поступают от пользователя)

самое четкое правило :)

если id - это число, то можно например:

$file = dirname(__FILE__).'/up/' . (int)$_GET['id'] . '.' . 'png';

Comment: @Zayac Проблема похоже в .htaccess, а не скрипте. Покажите .htaccess файл.

Comment: Кроме проверки GET данных добавить бы правило проверки существования файла - file_exists($file). И/ для вывода файла небезопасно использовать относительный путь.

Comment: @shurik На сервере стоит Nginx, соответственно никакого .htaccess там нет.
 
Конфиг nginx можно посмотреть тут: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6456403/

При вот таком коде: http://pastebin.com/x6KvxkPW

    2013/11/22 08:41:23 [error] 27831#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant FILE - assumed 'FILE' in /home/zayac/web/img-up/img2.php on line 3" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: img.loc, request: "GET /img2.php?id=123456 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "img.loc"

Comment: Вы зачем __ удалили в FILE ?

должно быть так:

     $file = dirname(__FILE__).'/up/' . (int)$_GET['id'] . '.' . 'png';

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо, решил проблему добавлением строк:

```
imageAlphaBlending($im, true);
imageSaveAlpha($im, true);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagePng($im);
```

Весь код получился следущим:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
$file = dirname(__FILE__).'/up/' . (int)$_GET['id'] . '.' . 'png';
$im = imagecreatefrompng($file);
imageAlphaBlending($im, true);
imageSaveAlpha($im, true);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagePng($im);
}
else
echo 'не указан id';
?>
```